# How to disable Auto Save in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, autosave

Is there way to disable auto save in Android Studio?

I have already unchecked "Save files automatically if application is idle for n sec"

under **Setting->General**.

Anything else to be done?

Comment: I am with you on this issue, I hate that auto save crap too! AS reminds me of iOS IDEs; hand holding tools/features. But to answer your question, there is no way of stopping the auto saving. Sucks.

Comment: I'm running version 2022.1.1 and am seeing "Autosave cannot be completely disabled" :/

Answer (score 48):

## Disable Autosave

> `File` > `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Autosave` > then uncheck both `Save files if the IDE is idle for |15| seconds` and `Save files when switching to a different application` > `Apply`

[image: Screenshot- Disable Auto Save]

---

After doing the above, you may like to do enable the following 2 options too-

## Mark Changed But Unsaved File

> `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Editor Tabs` > then check `Mark modified (*)` > `Apply`

[image: Screenshot- Mark Changed But Unsaved File]

## Save One File with Ctrl+S

> `File` > `Settings` > `Keymap` > search with **save document** > right click `Save Document` > `Add Keyboard Shortcut` > press **Ctrl+S**> `OK` > `Remove` > `Apply`

[image: Screenshot- Save One File with Ctrl+S]

Comment: Very good explanation, but the IDE still auto-saves the files you're working on. There seems to be no way to stop it.

Answer (score 18):

In android Studio 2.1.1,   2016

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Appearance and Behavior** -> **System Settings**
And see **synchronization** paragraph and uncheck autosave and/or 'use safe write'

Comment: @kalpaj, whats wrong with **"File -> Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings And see synchronization paragraph and uncheck autosave and/or 'use safe write'"**

Answer (score 8):

If you go to Settings, and type Save in the search you will find under the IDE Settings an area called "General". From there you can find a number of options to control saving. It sometimes does not work and saving will continue anyway. Unfortunately there is no universal "turn-off" switch. AS is a hand holding IDE, you just have to get use to it.

Settings section you are seeking looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

**For Android Studio v3.3**

- Open Settings (`Ctrl+Alt+S` or `File->Settings`)
- On the top left corner of the settings menu, search for "save" in the search bar field
- Click on System Settings and all the sub-settings related to save will be highlighted

  [image: Auto Save in v3.3]
- Uncheck **Save files automatically if application is idle for * sec**
- Click on apply and close the settings menu.

It is highly recommended to follow this method 
[Mark Changed But Unsaved File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193319/how-to-see-which-files-have-not-been-saved-in-android-studio/48018310#48018310) which will help you distinguish between your unsaved and saved files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just downgraded Android Studio.

Before downgrade: **Android Studio Giraffe | *Patch 2***
After downgrade: **Android Studio Giraffe | *Patch 1***