# Configure autosave on Android Studio to save more often

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta 5
```

During using Android studio sometimes in crashes unexpectedly and I tend to lose my work.

I have looked at the settings to try and find out if I can adjust the auto save to save more often to prevent the lose of work.

Normally I will `Ctrl X + S` Emacs keybindings if I haven't built anything for a while. However, sometimes I forget and lose any unsaved work when AS unexpectedly freezes or crashes.

Is there anyway to configure the auto save to get it to save more often, or is there anything else I can do?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Use GIT  for better approach .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946013/how-to-disable-auto-save-save-in-android-studio

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I use github for all my projects. But that will not auto save if AS freezes or crashes. As use Fedora 26 I sometimes can use sync to write all date in memory to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File/Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S)
Type in the search bar : "Autosave"
You can check the box for "Saves files if the IDE is idle for x seconds"

If the delay is too long, you can also reduce it.